# Xcode - failed to get the task for process -1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad, sigkill

This is my first post, this site normally has the answer to my question but not this time.

I am developing a universal iPhone/iPad app and have created all of the views in the iPhone storyboard and linked them to the relevant view controllers.

I started to work through my iPad storyboard this weekend after collecting my new iPad Air and i keep running into this error "failed to get the task for process -1", this completely locks the iPad so that i have to perform a hard reset.

If i deselect the view controller from the main storyboard scene then close/reopen Xcode and reconnect the view controller it sometimes works for a couple of times.

Posts on here suggest memory problems as i am seeing the following in the console"ios exited abnormally with signal 9: Killed: 9"

This view is extremely basic and has 3 IBACTIONS connected to NSLOG outputs for the time being.

The view scene has around 10 png uiimageviews, 2 uilabels and 2 unbuttons.

The app runs fine on iPhone but crashes the iPad.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try searching first?  This seems like a familiar one.

Comment: Yes trojanfoe ive spent a good 3 hours searching but cannot seem to get any of the "Fixes" to work. It points towards major memory leak but i am hardly using anything. Extremely frustrating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode GM Version 5.0.2 (5A3005) has resolved this issue.

Comment: Thankyou very much, downloaded 5.0.2 and it solved it instantly. Was tearing my hair out about this!